# Как настроить Visual Studio Code на работу с С++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

как настроить Visual Studio Code на работу с С++ после установки нужных плагинов? Visual Studio не подходит, ест много ресурсов, да и функционал немного другой.

Comment: Документацию читали?

Comment: Компилятор установлен? VSCode просто навороченный блокнот.

Comment: Visual Studio ест меньше ресурсов, VS Code - это же браузерное решение.

Comment: нужно мало ресурсов - vim/emacs наше все:)

Comment: *"после установки нужных плагинов"* Вопрос интересно поставлен. Половина настройки как раз в выборе хороших плагинов... Что вы уже поставили?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Уважаемый usernameusername,

примерно год назад я точно так же не мог с первого раза настроить VS Code.

Как справедливо указали в комментариях - есть прекрасная [официальная документация по настройке](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw). Тем не менее, я оставлю свой ответ, так как он более детальный в некоторых моментах. А в других моментах - менее детальный :-)

Чтобы настроить VSC, хорошо бы научиться компилировать и запускать Вашу программу из командной строки. А потом настройки, котрые для этого понадобились, добавить в правильные места в файлах конфигурации VS code.

Труднность этого процесса именно в "зоопарке" разных возможностей. На этого не стоит пугаться.

Кроме того, настройка немного отличатся для разных систем (Linux, windows, macos), а Вы не указали, какая система у вас.

Я приведу пример настройки для компилятора gcc под Win64. Можно повторить мои шаги, а когда получится - сделать самостотельную настройку, например, на другой компилятор.

0. Устанавливаем msys2. Я установил его в `C:\Programs\msys64`. При этом сам msys2 позаботился о том, чтобы путь к его директории `C:\Programs\msys64\mingw64\bin` оказался в path. Проверить это можно, выполнив в консоли команду `path`
1. Устанавливаем компилятор и дебаггер. Я делаю это с помощью пакета msys2, выполнив в окне, котрое открывает msys2, следующие команды:

   ```
    pacman -Syuu
   ```

   Эта команда обновляет msys2. Она может закрыть консоль - это нормально, нужно перезапустить ее и ввести ту же команду, чтобы завершить обновление. Хорошей идеей будет время от времени обновляться, чтобы всегда иметь последнюю версию компилятора.

   Затем:

   ```
    pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc
    pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gdb
   ```

Теперь в Вашей системе есть компилятор и дебаггер. Проверить это просто: открываем новое окно консоли, пишем `g++ --version`

Если ответом не является версия - надо поискать, что пошло не так. Проверить path, возможно, отредактировать его вручную.

Такую же проверку хорошо бы сделат для дебаггера: `gdb --version`

2. Пишем hello world. Это позволит нам окончательно убедиться, что компилятор работает. в любой директории созадем файл hello.cpp с текстом

   ```
    #include <iostream>
    int main() {
        std::cout << "Hello world!" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    };
   ```

потом в этой папке в командной строке компилируем командой `g++ hello.cpp -o hello.exe`
Если появился файл hello.exe, и он запускается и вывоит строчку - ок, этот шаг завершен.

3. А вот теперь можно поставить VSC. Обратите внимание, что редакций есть несколько, во первых для 32 и 64 битных систем, а во вторых - то, что назывется "User Installer" и "System Installer". Выбираем 64 битный System Installer на [странице загрузки](https://code.visualstudio.com/#alt-downloads)
4. В VSC ставим расширение для работы с C++, оно называется `C/C++ for Visual Studio Code` и написано Microsoft
5. Теперь запустим VSC в папке Вашего проекта. Пусть это будет папка `C:\Projects\`. Делается это так: запускам консоль. Переходим в консоли в папку (`cd C:\Projects\`). Запускаем VSC командой `code .`.

Важно то, что при этом создаётся папка настроек VSC, котрые находятся по пути `C:\Projects\.vscode`. В этой папке нужно создать 4 файла, я приведу их в минимальном варианте. Пути - для моей системы, где msys2 установлен в `C:\Programs\msys64\`.

Файл **tasks.json** - отвечает за то, чтобы работала комбинация клавиш Ctrl+shift+B для сборки программы:

```
    {
        "version": "2.0.0",
        "tasks": [
            {
                "type": "shell",
                "label": "g++.exe build active file",
                "command": "C:/Programs/msys64/mingw64/bin/g++.exe",
                "args": [
                    "-std=c++17",
                    "-g",
                    "${file}",
                    "-o",
                    "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
                ],
                "options": {
                    "cwd": "C:\\Programs\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin"
                },
                "problemMatcher": [
                    "$gcc"
                ],
                "group": {
                    "kind": "build",
                    "isDefault": true
                }

            }
        ]
    }
```

Файл **launch.json** - отвечает за работу дебаггера:

```
    {
        "version": "0.2.0",
        "configurations": [
            {
                "name": "g++.exe build and debug active file",
                "type": "cppdbg",
                "request": "launch",
                "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
                "args": [],
                "stopAtEntry": false,
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
                "environment": [],
                "externalConsole": false,
                "MIMode": "gdb",
                "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\Programs\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\gdb.exe",
                "setupCommands": [
                    {
                        "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                        "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                        "ignoreFailures": true
                    }
                ],
                "preLaunchTask": "g++.exe build active file",
                "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Файл **settings.json** - как то отвечает за файловые ассоциации, возможно даже, что он не особо нужен. Но лишним не будет:

```
    {
        "files.associations": {
            "ostream": "cpp",
            "iostream": "cpp",
            "iomanip": "cpp",
            "chrono": "cpp",
            "iosfwd": "cpp",
            "thread": "cpp",
            "array": "cpp",
            "string_view": "cpp",
            "initializer_list": "cpp",
            "utility": "cpp",
            "valarray": "cpp",
            "optional": "cpp",
            "sstream": "cpp"
        }
    }
```

Файл **c_cpp_properties.json** - отвечает за расположение include - файлов:

```
    {
        "configurations": [
            {
                "name": "Win32",
                "includePath": [
                    "${workspaceFolder}/**", 
                    "C:/Programs/msys64/mingw64/include/**"
                ],
                "defines": [
                    "_DEBUG",
                    "UNICODE",
                    "_UNICODE"
                ],
                "windowsSdkVersion": "8.1",
                "compilerPath": "C:\\Programs\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
                "cStandard": "c11",
                "cppStandard": "c++17",
                "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x86"
            }
        ],
        "version": 4
    }
```

Если Вы создадите эти файлы, а потом заново запустите в этой директории VSC - то всё уже должно работать. То есть, программы на C++ будут компилироваться, запускаться в отладке (по F5) и показывать значения переменных в окне отладчика.

Теперь - самое важное. Как только заработает - Вам нужно эту папку .vscode копировать к корень каждой папки с проектом на C++. Это позволит VSC запускаться с Вашими настройками.

Даже если мой способ Вам не подходит напрямую - у Вас теперь есть все необходимые ключевые слова, чтобы использовать их для гуглежа.

Успехов!

PS. Время от времени попадаются полезные дополнительные возможности для настройки.

Вот такой фрагмент файла tasks.json позволяет очищать окно терминала перед каждым билдом - полезно, чтобы уже не видеть уже исправленных ошибок, оставшихся от предыдущей попытки сборки ([Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46221272/)):

```
    "presentation": {
            "clear": true                        // <-- this line
      }
```

Comment: Ссылка на официальную инструкцию: [Get Started with C++ and Mingw-w64 in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw)

Comment: [pacman -Sy vs -Syu](https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/5111je/pacman_sy_vs_syu/)

Comment: Думаю лучше вместо `pacman -Sy` делать `pacman -Syuu`. Первая скачивает новый список пакетов, но не обновляет установленные пакеты. (А если MSYS2 попросит закрыться для завершения обновления - нужно написать ту же команду второй раз.)