# Настройка Visual Studio Code под C++ код и его запуск

Tags: c++

Visual Studio Code весьма ... геморройный в плане настройке, вынуждает пытаться пользоваться им. Из за приятного интерфейса и низкой настройки на комп. Вся проблема, что ни один язык, кроме Python. Не выходить подключить к редактору, от слова совсем. Вопрос - как это исправить ?

P.s: Code Runner не спасает, а только выводит абракадабру

Comment: Что исправить то?

Comment: Я обычно использую связку cmake, gcc, cmake tools

Comment: Настройку и запуск C++ кода в редакторе

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как настроить Visual Studio Code на работу с С++?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1172843/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-visual-studio-code-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d1%83-%d1%81-%d0%a1)

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, Вам может помочь вот этот ответ на похожий вопрос:

c++ - Как настроить Visual Studio Code на работу с С++? - Stack Overflow на русском
[https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1172843/Как-настроить-visual-studio-code-на-работу-с-С](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1172843/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-visual-studio-code-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%83-%D1%81-%D0%A1)