# vscode не видит путь к gcc

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, wsl

У меня в этом пути дистрибутив линукса(через wsl). Он видит только файл образа диска. Можно ли поменять корень поиска с винды на линукс? Помогите
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Извините, Вы ставите вопрос неправильно.

Когда Вы используете VSC для программирования на С++ на винде, то у Вас есть 2 пути:

1. Работать полностью в винде. Тогда - надо поставить минимальный набор софта, который включает в себя компилятор и дебаггер. По моему, самая "протоптанная" дорожка здесь - посавить gcc и gdb, поспользовавшись [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/) , и, конечно же, поставить extension для языка C++ (@ext:ms-vscode.cpptools)
2. Вы можете настроить удаленную компиляцию и отладку в WSL (WSL2, если говорить о последней версии). Тогда у Вас в винде запускается VSC, он коннектится к language server, запущенному в WSL, и всё тоже очень хорошо работает. Интерфейсно это выглядит как зеленый квадратик в левой нижнйе части окна VSC, на котором написано WSL.

И тот, и другой способы - описаны в [документации](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp), а также в других вопросах-ответах на этом сайте, например, [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1172843)

Если на этом пути у Вас возникнут проблемы - Вы можете уточнить свой вопрос, и, скорее всего, проблему можно будет решить. Но пока Вы делаете, извините, что то не то :-)