# Как без проблем компилировать код на C в VS Code

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, компиляция

Я тут новенький во всём этом деле, поэтому для меня поподробней))
Хочу изучать Си, но при входе в Vs Code глаза разбегаются, создал только файл .c немного кода написал там, а скомпилировать не могу. Непонятно что и куда устанавливать и тыкать, установил расширения ещё, все от Microsoft: C/C++; Thems C/C++.

Заранее спасибо

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего, у Вас проблема с тем, что в системе не установлен компилятор C++.

В отличие от более "взрослой" Visual Studio, VSC не приносит с собой компилятор, и представляет собой такой "блокнот на стероидах": это редактор кода, но для компиляции он использует внешнюю программу.

Соответсвенно, редактор нужно просто правильно настроить.

Не так давно я писал [инструкцию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1172843/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-visual-studio-code-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%83-%D1%81-%D0%A1), которая до сих пор актуальна, попробуйте все сделать по ней. Ну, или по официальной инструкции, ссылка на неё там тоже есть.