# Как правильно установить C++?

Tags: c++, компилятор

Решил изучать C++. Но столкнулся с проблемой: нет официального компилятора. Когда изучал Go - надо было с сайта go.dev просто скачать установщик, с помощью которого за пару кликов можно было установить Go. А вот C++... В Интернете множество разных вариантов: G++ MSYS2, Clang, встроенные компиляторы в Qt и Visual Studio и так далее.

Собственно, вот мой вопрос: Как правильно установить C++?

Comment: Выбрать один, и следовать инструкции по установке...

Comment: А какой выбрать? Мне нужно, чтобы с помощью одного можно было скомпилировать программы под Windows, Linux, macOS. Есть такой?

Comment: Дмитрий, ну вы тут всех знатоков прямо в тупик поставили.. все такие мнутся, не знают, что сказать... вообще то - есть, GCC называется.

Comment: Любой из них, тут больше зависит от личных предпочтений и уровня опыта. Если вообще не хочется разбираться с ключами и опциями, можно использовать и Visual studio. Я привык к gcc - им и пользуюсь.

Comment: С помощью одного скомпилировать программы под разные платформы не получится. Для этого надо будет ставить несколько и задействовать кросс-компиляцию. Кроме того, вы еще удивитесь, но один компилятор может собирать программы очень по-разному, в связи с чем библиотеки в С++ можно задействовать только когда они собраны этим же компилятором, причем с совместимыми настройками. Для начала стоит поставить Visual Studio.

Comment: официальный есть только стандарт языка. У каждой архитектуры свой компилятор.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Но столкнулся с проблемой: нет официального компилятора

Думаю, что для **изучения** языка официальный компилятор не нужен. Несколько компиляторов, которые в среднем реализуют один стандарт языка - это плата за очень большое кол-во платформ, на которых язык работает, и за длительное историческое наследие. И в то же время, из-за такого разнообразия получается  поддерживать некую "внутреннюю конкуренцию", и новые элементы стандарта оперативно реализуются в разных компиляторах.

Для изучения языка, как мне кажется, имеет смысл говорить о "минимальном наборе инструментов", на котором можно решать учебные задачи.

Когда учебные задачи закончатся, и перед Вами встанут "боевые" - то у Вас уже будет достаточно опыта, чтобы и под них подобрать набор инструментов (Ну, мы то знаем, что с высокой вероятностью - это будет компилятор GCC).

Если Вы пользуетесь Windows - то у вас два очевидных варианта: [Visual Studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/ru/) или [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) + [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/).

Есть [мой ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1172843/) о том, как эту комбинацию устанавливать.

Если Вы пользуетесь маком, то там есть прекрасный Clang, и что-то от JetBrains (CLion, если быть точным) в качестве IDE. Ну, или опять таки, VSC.

Для linux - выбор очень широк, но, похоже, от GCC+VSC - не убежишь :-).

Несмотря на мой ядовитый комментарий, я так же решил развернуто написать "А почему так?".

Дело в том, что Go и C++ - это инструменты для немного разного. Для немного разного *всего*.

В каком то смысле, Go - это такая "джава на минималках". Очень простой язык, пишешь - практически под виртуальную машину. В основном пишешь рест-сервисы, но можно писать что-то, что связано более производительными протобаф- протоколами, и тогда получается "почти реалтайм" (Ну, если сборщик мусора не придёт :-) ).

Графика? - Не, не слышали.

Библиотеки? - А вот тут у наc кватн либ есть, её все банкиры любят...

Короче, Go - это очень молодой язык, в котором удаётся "держать всё под контролем", и всё, связанное с этим языком, сделано в стиле "бедно, но чистенько".

Хорошо это, или плохо?

Это **офигенно**, если это язык, с которым вы *начали* разбираться. Это очень и очень удобно, когда вам не хочется заморачиваться с деталями. Модели памяти? - Не, не знаем. Треды или грин треды? - понятия не имею! Вот какие есть - такими и будем пользоваться, к тому же, у нас всё равно всё на корутинах. Как оно там скомпилируется, в команды какого процессора, сколько памяти сожрет? Ну, сразу и не скажешь :-).

В отличие от Go, С++ - это невероятный монстр.

В нём есть **всё**, и в нескольких вариантах. Причем, если какой то вариант Вас не устраивает, Вы можете лёгким движением руки (Ну, полгода там, год - максимум :-) пописав. ) сделать свою версию какого-нибудь хитрого аллокатора или запредельно умного указателя.

Графика? под какую платформу? Все игры - это либо свои движки на плюсах, либо, Unreal (опять таки, с торчащими оттуда C++-ушами), либо не очень широкий круг Unity 3D, но это уже под C# - платформу.

Загрузчик для железки, которая полетит в космос? Ага, вот вам библиотеки, вот референсный код, вот гайд по работе с флешкой. Не забудьте добавить такие то флаги компилятора.

Именно из за этой "ширины поляны" и нет единого способа установки и эксплуатации C++. Потому что для решения олимпиадных задачек нужно одно, для сборки ядра - немного другое, а для профессиональной работы с кодом игр - вообще третье.

И очень, очень много времени уходит на овладение инструментами, которые используются в процессе. Пакетный менеджер, системы сборки, IDE, системы, которые ищут утечки памяти, автотесты, все-все-все... я подозреваю, что многого из этих инструментов просто нет для Go - например, потому что они не нужны.

Comment: Хм, за рекордное время моему ответу минус прилетел, прям и 5 секунд не прошло... а поговорить?

Comment: S.H., спасибо Вам за развёрнутый ответ! Я всё понял. Переформулирую вопрос: какой компилятор C++ выбрать для создания десктоп-приложения под Windows 10/11?

Comment: я там свой ответ тоже исправил, чтобы не впадать в тон "слишком опытного советчика"... Вариантов два - Visual Studio и Qt. Лично я бы выбрал Visual Studio и смотрел в сторону MAUI - https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/maui/what-is-maui Не смотрите, что там написано "для C#" - там, наконец то, вызовы - кроссплатформенные

Comment: Понял. Спасибо Вам огромное!

Comment: @ДмитрийКраснов - успехов Вам, и запаситесь терпением, для C++ оно понадобится :-)

Comment: S.H., спасибо :)

Comment: Вау, это действительно хороший ответ!

Comment: @Bloody.cpp - спасибо за такую оценку, и за тщательные правки, которые улучшили мой ответ!

Comment: "С++ - это невероятный монстр" - хорошо сказано. В этом языке я бы выделил две главные "монстроузные" особенности: 1) чем больше ты знаешь C++, тем больше понимаешь, что нифига не знаешь C++; 2) если ты написал программу на C++ и она работает, то это не значит, что программа написана верно.))