Ошибка при попытке ввести данные на input в debug console на c++ VSCode
Только только начал изучать c++ и впервые работаю с VSCode так что возможно вопрос для вас покажется глупым, при попытке ввести данные в debug cosole выдает ошибку(Возможно нужно вводить не в debug console просто я не понимаю куда еще) в коде ошибок вроде нету прикреплю его ниже, компилятор использую g++
#include <iostream>
int main(){
    введите сюда код`setlocale(LC_ALL, "RU");
    int a,b;
    std::cout<<"Enter first and third nums";
    std::cin>>a;
    std::cout<<a+b;
}


Попробуйте проверить настройки: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1172843/ И напишите, какая именно у вас ошибка. И вообще то код некорретный - посмотрите на третью строку, ту, которая сразу после слова main
