Как отключить вывод путей компилятора в терминал c++ vscode
При запуске любого cpp файла в vscode вместе с программой в терминал выводится много лишней информации, часто теряюсь среди всего этого. Подскажите, возможно ли это скрыть, чтобы в терминале была только программа?
PS D:\need\test>  & 'c:\Users\lextm\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.cpptools-1.22.11-win32-x64\debugAdapters\bin\WindowsDebugLauncher.exe' '--stdin=Microsoft-MIEngine-In-sb5k4ajr.xw5' '--stdout=Microsoft-MIEngine-Out-d0c4xqhy.ru0' '--stderr=Microsoft-MIEngine-Error-eomsugsy.kob' '--pid=Microsoft-MIEngine-Pid-xu3ghdcq.3fv' '--dbgExe=C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\gdb.exe' '--interpreter=mi'
rosoft-MIEngine-Error-eomsugsy.kob' '--pid=Microsoft-MIEngine-Pid-xu3ghdcq.3fv' '--dbgExe=C:\x5cmsys64\x5cmingw64\x5cbin\x5cgdb.exe' '--interpreter=mi' ;be815089-7ab7-4c95-836a-3f1c9e2f0f07


может тут есть => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1172843/264178
